# CSS can a div automatically be sized to fit the rest of the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page I'm creating where I want to have to columns the first colomn has a fixed a sized and the second column has to fill the rest of the window width. This is what I came up so far but it doesn't seen to work.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="nav"></div>
        <div class="page">my page content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0;
}
#container > div{
    color: white;
}
.nav{
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#666;
}
.page{
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/scNSL/)

Answer (score 4):

Just remove `float: left` and add `width: 100%` to `.page`

http://jsfiddle.net/scNSL/2/

Comment: IMO, `width : auto` is better : You can then use fixed value for padding/margin/border.

Comment: That's right, I was thinking the simplest solution for the given example.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, alternatively, making use of `box-sizing: border-box` can help if you need a fixed or percent-based width.

Comment: So, in essence just remove `float: left;`

Comment: @zzzzBov That's true, but ie8 doesnt support it. Only depend what are the condition of the OP ;)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, [actually it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). You might be thinking of `padding-box`.

Comment: This has [issues with borders](http://jsfiddle.net/scNSL/6/), which [an alternate solution does not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427183/css-can-a-div-automatically-be-sized-to-fit-the-rest-of-the-browser/20427245#20427245).

Answer (score 0):

### True Fit (allows for borders)

Change to this ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scNSL/3/)):

```
.page{
    height:500px;
    overflow: hidden; /* or auto */
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

By not floating the `.page`, and setting an `overflow` other than `visible`, the browser fills a block level element with the space beside the floated element ([good explanation here](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)).

**Why this can be better than setting `width: 100%`**

Compare these `div` elements with borders. [One with](http://jsfiddle.net/scNSL/6/) `width` at `100%`, [one with](http://jsfiddle.net/scNSL/5/) the `overflow` set as above.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/scNSL/4/

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="nav"></div>
        Inhalt
    </div>
</div>

#container{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0;
}
#container > div{
    color: white;
}
.nav{
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#666;
}
.page{
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.page{
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

**Note:** Removed `float:left;` & added `width:100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing it myself...

Check out this article for more information:
http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Should help you learn more about equal height columns 100% height etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0;
}
#container > div{
    color: white;
}
.nav{
    width:40%;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#666;
}
.page{
    height:500px;
    width: 60%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The classical way of creating a fixed + fluid column layout is to float an element next to another element with padding:

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav"></div>
    <div class="page">content</div>
</div>
```

<sub>CSS (float):</sub>

```
.container {
    color: #FFF;
}

.nav {
    background-color: #666;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.page {
    background-color: #333;
    height: 200px;
    padding-left: 200px;
}
```

This has some drawbacks, particularly when the `.nav` and `.page` elements have differing heights, or when you want to add a border around the `.page` element.

The modern way of creating a fixed + fluid column layout is to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes):

```
.container {
    color: #FFF;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.nav {
    background-color: #666;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.page {
    background-color: #333;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    height: 200px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uRva/) <sub>(pardon the [BEM](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/) classes, they're used so that the difference in CSS between these two methods can be seen more readily)</sub>